# Trigger to Count records in self relationship salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I am working on one scenario.

I have an object called "Property_Assignment__c" which has two record types.
1) Primary Property Assignment
2) Secondary Property Assignment
Its also having a self lookup relationship and this lookup field "Primary_Assignemnt__c" is available on "Secondary Property Assignment" page layout which is lookup to "Primary Property Assignment".
Now if I create any records in "Secondary Property Assignment" record type then I need to count and save in "Number_Of__Dependents" field in "Primary Property Assignment".
Can anyone help me to solve this problem if possible please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the Secondary Property Assignment records you should go with trigger only. we can use Rollup summary to count the no of Secondary Property Assignment records when the master-detail relationship is available.

But here u have self-relationship. So you can write a trigger to count the no of records.

Comment: Thanks for the update and I have achieved it with trigger.